# Html parser ignores img tag (Golang)

Tags: go

My task is to find images urls inside an html

**The problem**

Html parser `golang.org/x/net/html` as well as 
`github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery` igonores the biggest image on the page http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34498204/

**The question**

- What is wrong in my code
- Why required `img` tag with `src=""` is ignored?
- Is there are way to get all images from html with go?

**Notes:**

- When i used [parser written in Swift](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) this image has been found on the page `//static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/spare_covers/1013531536.jpg`
- This image tag has been found when i use regex search.
- This image tag has been found when i use third party service [saveallimages.com](http://saveallimages.com/)
- I tried to use gokogiri but has no success to compile it on my mac. `Go get` is successful, but `Go build` stuck forever.

**Parsed html page source**

[This is the html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-eomJ7SS0EVElORE1Sd3JDaTA) which is result of `resp, _ := http.Get(url)`

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
  "golang.org/x/net/html"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)


func main() {

  url := "http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34498204/"

  if resp, err := http.Get(url); err == nil {
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    log.Println("Load page complete")

    if resp != nil {
      log.Println("Page response is NOT nil")

      if document, err := html.Parse(resp.Body); err == nil {

        var parser func(*html.Node)
        parser = func(n *html.Node) {
          if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "img" {

            var imgSrcUrl, imgDataOriginal string

            for _, element := range n.Attr {
              if element.Key == "src" {
                imgSrcUrl = element.Val
              }
              if element.Key == "data-original" {
                imgDataOriginal = element.Val
              }
            }

            log.Println(imgSrcUrl, imgDataOriginal)
          }

          for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
            parser(c)
          }

        }
        parser(document)
      } else {
        log.Panicln("Parse html error", err)
      }

    } else {
      log.Println("Page response IS nil")
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think you also filed the issue on [https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16318](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16318) a couple of minutes ago. I think this is related to that since the image is in a `noscript` tag

Comment: @DonovanSolms thank you. I linked this post in the thread you linked.

Comment: @DonovanSolms I filed the issue. And yes it is related :-)

Comment: @georg [here is the fix](https://github.com/bearburger/net/commit/42ac75393ced8c48137b574278522df1f3fa2cec) if you need it right there right now and able to fix package code. The behaviour of `x/net/html` (`<noscript>` content as text) is not unexpected according to their tests.

Comment: @RomanR. thank you. So someone of you guys post the answer which i can accept as the solution?

Comment: @georg There is no solution yet :-) But ok I can post the link to issue and the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug but expected behaviour of `x/net/html` which affects all parsers based on `x/net/html`.

There are four possible solutions:

1. Remove `<noscript>` and `</noscript>` in HTML so `x/net/html` would parse its content as expected. Something like:

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "golang.org/x/net/html"
       "log"
       "net/http"
       "io/ioutil"
       "strings"
   )

   func main() {

       url := "http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34498204/"

       if resp, err := http.Get(url); err == nil {
           defer resp.Body.Close()

           log.Println("Load page complete")

           if resp != nil {
               log.Println("Page response is NOT nil")
               // --------------
               data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
               resp.Body.Close()

               hdata := strings.Replace(string(data), "<noscript>", "", -1)
               hdata = strings.Replace(hdata, "</noscript>", "", -1)
               // --------------

               if document, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(hdata)); err == nil {
                   var parser func(*html.Node)
                   parser = func(n *html.Node) {
                       if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "img" {

                           var imgSrcUrl, imgDataOriginal string

                           for _, element := range n.Attr {
                               if element.Key == "src" {
                                   imgSrcUrl = element.Val
                               }
                               if element.Key == "data-original" {
                                   imgDataOriginal = element.Val
                               }
                           }

                           log.Println(imgSrcUrl, imgDataOriginal)
                       }

                       for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
                           parser(c)
                       }

                   }
                   parser(document)
               } else {
                   log.Panicln("Parse html error", err)
               }

           } else {
               log.Println("Page response IS nil")
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. Patch `x/net/html` with https://github.com/bearburger/net/commit/42ac75393ced8c48137b574278522df1f3fa2cec
3. Use gokogiri with go 1.4 (I'm pretty sure this is last version supported)
4. Wait for decision on https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16318 If this is real bug I'll make the pull request.